# Show a column that's currently in seconds in hours?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a column called title_runtime that's in seconds that I want to show in hours, and also show only columns where the runtime is over three hours. This is what I have, minus the conversion:

```
select title_name, title_type, title_release_year, title_runtime as title_runtime_hrs
from nf_titles
where title_release_year = '1999' or
    title_release_year = '2000' or
    title_release_year = '2001' and
    title_runtime > 3
order by title_release_year, title_runtime_hrs
```

Comment: Can you please clarify whether you want a runtime of `10975` seconds to show as `3:02:55` or `3.048611`?

Comment: I want it shown in 3.048611.

Comment: Should the `title_runtime` condition apply to all three years or only the year 2001? If the former, you need to enclose the `or`s into brackets: `(title_release_year = '1999' or ... or ...) and ...`. Or just use `IN` instead: `title_release_year in ('1999', '2000', '2001') and ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the both in the divide operation are `int` the result will be `int`.

Try this:

```
select title_name, title_type, title_release_year, title_runtime / 3600.0 as title_runtime_hrs
from nf_titles
where title_release_year = '1999' or
    title_release_year = '2000' or
    title_release_year = '2001' and
    title_runtime > 3*3600
order by title_release_year, title_runtime_hrs
```

Comment: @AndriyM If you about `>`, then it is just an idea not an exact solution :)

Comment: No, it was about the `or`s not enclosed in brackets. May not be an issue but could be. It is not clear from the question that the OP wants the runtime condition to apply to 2001 only, so... I'd mention it.

Comment: And as for `title_runtime > 3*3600`, personally I actually like it much better than `title_runtime/3600.0 > 3`.

Comment: @AndriyM Of course, sargable predicates are much better, what about `WHERE` clause, just OP mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

To get a precise measurement of hours, you need to divide by 3600.0. Not just 3600. If you divide by 3600 you will never get an accurate amount of hours. For example, if the runtime is an hour 1/2, you need the result to be 1.5 hours. This is not possible without dividing by 3600.0.

```
SELECT title_name, title_type, title_release_year, title_runtime / 3600.0 as title_runtime_hrs
FROM nf_titles
WHERE title_release_year = '1999' or
title_release_year = '2000' or
title_release_year = '2001' and
title_runtime > (3.0 * 3600.0)
order by title_release_year, title_runtime_hrs
```

Comment: While this is probably so, the OP could be not caring about the fractional part. For all we know, the items stored have a runtime of months... (upvoted btw)

Comment: Invalid column name `title_runtime_hrs`!

Answer (score 1):

divide column title_runtime by 3600 .

```
select title_name, title_type, title_release_year, title_runtime/3600 as title_runtime_hrs
from nf_titles
where title_release_year = '1999' or
    title_release_year = '2000' or
    title_release_year = '2001' and
    title_runtime > 3*3600
order by title_release_year, title_runtime_hrs
```

Above query is wrong , we need to force floating point division otherwise something like 1200 / 3600 will show column value as zero .

```
title_runtime / 3600.0 as title_runtime_hrs
```

Comment: The where clause is wrong as well. `title_runtime/3600` will lead to a rounded-down int result, which means a movie with a runtime of `3:59:59` will get left out.