# Mix of AND / OR in WHERE clause leads to unexpected results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

What I'm trying to do with the statement is show all of the movies released in 1999, 2000, and 2001 that run over three hours (the actual column is in seconds).

The output table is showing the correct years, but it's showing other things for title_type other than movie, and it's showing times less than three (as well as greater than three) in title_runtime_hrs.

This is my code:

```
select title_name, title_type, title_release_year, 
    (title_runtime / 3600.0) as title_runtime_hrs
from nf_titles
where title_type = 'Movie' and
    title_runtime > 3 and
    title_release_year = '1999' or
    title_release_year = '2000' or
    title_release_year = '2001' 
order by title_release_year, title_runtime_hrs desc
```

Comment: I asked you about missing brackets [in a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19182922/show-a-column-thats-currently-in-seconds-in-hours#comment28382698_19182922) to one of your previous questions, along with suggestions of how to fix the (then potential) issue. Why did you have to post this question when you already had a solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or do it this way

```
select title_name, title_type, title_release_year, (title_runtime / 3600.0) as title_runtime_hrs
from nf_titles
where title_type = 'Movie' and
    title_runtime > 3 and
    title_release_year in ('1999','2000','2001')
order by title_release_year, title_runtime_hrs desc
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to wrap your `OR` statements in parantheses. Otherwise SQL Server will say "ok, here's a year 2000, we've met the criteria.

```
select title_name, title_type, title_release_year, (title_runtime / 3600.0) as title_runtime_hrs
from nf_titles
where title_type = 'Movie' and
    title_runtime > 3 and
    (title_release_year = '1999' or
    title_release_year = '2000' or
    title_release_year = '2001' )
order by title_release_year, title_runtime_hrs desc
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably need brackets around your `OR` statements (this is because `AND` binds stronger than `OR`):

```
select title_name, title_type, title_release_year, (title_runtime / 3600.0) as title_runtime_hrs
from nf_titles
where title_type = 'Movie' and
    title_runtime > 3 and
    (
        title_release_year = '1999' or
        title_release_year = '2000' or
        title_release_year = '2001' 
    )
order by title_release_year, title_runtime_hrs desc
```